# How do I stream WITH FULLSCREEN for specific program in OBS?

Tags: recording, streaming, obs

Streaming fullscreen with Open Broadcaster Software gives black screen. There is another stackexchange question from 2013 asking this. The answer says OBS would add this feature in the future, but it does not appear to work in 2018. Is there a secret configuration method for this to work?

Automatic scene switcher is turned on and correctly identifies the program running in FullScreen mode and switches to the scene. Scene is set up correctly, using "Game Capture" module (not "Window capture" module) set to "Capture specific window" mode, not "Capture any fullscreen application" mode. I have also tested using "Capture any fullscreen application" mode, and this also fails to capture a blatantly fullscreen game.

I want to make sure that OBS does not accidentally switch to any other full-screen program while running a fullscreen game. I do not wish to use the work-around to change the game to Borderless-Windowed mode, as it drastically decreases frame-rate.

The "Game Capture" module with "Capture specific window" mode identifies and lists the program running in fullscreen mode, so this indicates it is compatible with this mode.

Comment: It could be a conflict between what OBS deems a fullscreen size and what your game considers a fullscreen. I know that if your using 2+ monitors that a full screen game can actually over hang the second monitor. I would suggest trying the game in a borderless window and trying to use the game capture instead of fullscreen capture.

Comment: Which game are we talking about?

Comment: +1 to previous, it would be helpful to know the game, its settings and the hardware in use to diagnose this.

Comment: "Indication of compatibility" is not a sure thing, especially with OBS. The game you're running is important here, as OBS cannot capture Vulkan-based games at the moment (ex. Wolfenstein II; The New Colossus).

Comment: Have we ruled out the possibility of in-game DRM (or platform DRM, like Steam) blocking the stream through third-party software like OBS?

Comment: @MacMan I very specifically do not want to use Windowed-fullscreen mode. I do not have multiple screens. Full screen games operate in a completely separate mode from normal applications, which is why they take so long to Alt+Tab in and out of. You'll also notice that Alt-Tabbing shows the game as blank/black until the full screen frame server and graphics engine kick in. Full screen mode gives full control over the monitor to the game and flushes the windows GUI from VRAM, but Windowed-full requires Windows GUI which eats up GPU and/or CPU resources, hence the drop in frame rate (fps).

Comment: @Stese the game does not matter, only the frame server/engine. This game in particular is called League Of Legends and is the single most streamed game in the world. There is ample evidence that it works with OBS.

Comment: @user141156 I was suggesting that you switch to a borderless-window for the purpose of testing your OBS settings to ensure that it is set up correctly. I know how fullscreen works, i am a software engineer. Glad you found a solution though, I would suggest you mark your answer so that anyone else having this problem can find it easily.

Answer (score 2):

OBS must be run with Administrator permissions in order to hook into the full screen rendering process.

So right click on the shortcut for OBS and click "Run as Administrator". This is tedious to do repeatedly, so, instead, right click on shortcut and click "Open File location" and do this over and over again, until you find the original .exe file in Windows Explorer (not a shortcut), then right click on the file, and click on the "Compatibility" tab, and then check-mark "Run this program as an administrator" and click "Apply" or "OK".

I discovered the answer in a Youtube comment on a video. The video itself did not have the answer. There is no competent answer anywhere else on the internet. The game is League of Legends, and running it in Windowed-Fullscreen is not an option.